# Can I rearrange the directories in `dirs` in the order of their most recent visits?

Tags: bash, pushd

What is the order for the pathnames of the directories stored in the stack shown by `dirs -l`?

Are they ordered by their last `pushd` commands?

Is it possible to order them so that they are ordered by their most recent visit times (a natural extension of `$OLDPATH`)?

Comment: Interesting commands. I did not know about them.

Answer (score 4):

It's a stack, with the most-recent `cd` entry on the left, and the list of `pushd` directories from the most recent on the left to the oldest on the right (or, with `-p`, the  most recent `cd` on top and the `pushd` list from oldest to newest, top-down).

You can reorder the list by editing the values of the `$DIRSTACK` array variable, but there's currently no built-in mechanism to re-sort the output of `dirs`.